# Cannot load image from an HttpUrlConnection (PNG to bitmap), Bitmap from inputStream is null

Tags: android, bitmap, httpurlconnection

I have researched in Stack Overflow and the internet for how I can load an image from an `URL` and show it on the App as a `Bitmap` (originally a `.png` file). I followed the instructions and have the codes as below, with the code in a class that extends `AsyncTask`.

```
try {
    imageUrl = new URL(currentApp.getImageURL());
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) 
    imageUrl.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);

    ***urlConnection.connect();
    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
    imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
    viewHolder.tvImage.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    inputStream.close();***

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
         Log.d(TAG, "getView: " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
         Log.d(TAG, "getView: " + e.toString());
    } finally {

}
```

As I used the debugging tool to assist me, I found that the response code from the connection is 200, but with `imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);`, I get null value for `imageBitmap`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: see the logcat, what is the cause of crashing.

Comment: are you running the code inside any thread?

Comment: what is your logcart message?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder that I should put it in a thread. Now I just put the code into a class that extends AsyncTask, it stops crashing.
But as I continued to try to get the bitmap from the source, even though the connection works, bitmap doesn't. I used the debugging tool to assist me, and realized the response code from the connection is 200, but with "imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);", I get null value for imageBitmap.

Can you help me?

Comment: check my answer...

Comment: test your url is ok...... copy the url and pest it in a browser.... if you see image it is ok....

Answer (score 0):

[Decode Stream](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeStream(java.io.InputStream)) return null If the input stream is null,or cannot be used to decode a bitmap. Try to download image from another url,i'm downloading thumbnail of YouTube playlist and its working 110% fine for me, try this code

```
 public class DownloadImagesTask extends AsyncTask<ImageView, Void, ImageView> {
    ImageView iv=null;
    Bitmap bitmap=null;
    String url=null;

    public DownloadImagesTask(ImageView iv,int position,String url) {
        this.iv = iv;
        this.position=position;
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected ImageView doInBackground(ImageView... url) {
        try {
                Log.e("url", this.url);
                URL ulrn = new URL(this.url);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) ulrn.openConnection();
                InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
                this.bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                if (null != this.bitmap)
                {
                    return iv;
                }
        }catch(Exception e){}
        return null;
    }




    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ImageView result) {
        if(result!=null) {
            this.iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }
        else
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading);
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I tried and the bitmap is still null

Comment: did you tried with another link? may be the link is broken ?

Comment: thanks for helping, but I didn't tried several links, all didn't work

Comment: @justinj can you show me logs? please make sure you have given internet permission in your manifest file

Comment: Thanks for helping! I actually did have the internet permission included in my manifest file. I just found out why I didn't get the desired result: I had the image showing before having the image downloaded. I fixed it by adjusting the AsyncTask so that the image is downloaded first and then show it.